# MacOS High Sierra lags to change input layout

Tags: keyboard, high-sierra, language

I have configured input switch with CapsLock. But Some times it takes several times pushing CapsLock key to change input language. Is it MacOS lag, or is it configuring some where?

[image]
[image]

p.s. I don't whant to use ctrl+space to change layout

Comment: whaT happened to command space to change the input language!??

Comment: It became control plus space a few years ago, and caps lock is an option for non Latin scripts starting with Sierra I think

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/226861)